Old film about a supposedly deaf mute boy
A friend of mine keeps going on about this old film from the 40's or 50's, but despite numerous web searches I keep coming up blank.
The plot is as follows;
A child is born, thought to be deaf and a mute. The father wanted to send him away to find out what was wrong with him. The kid wouldn't respond at school.
His mother brought him back but his father took no interest in him.
The boy falls off a cliff at the bottom of his garden. Was hanging on by his fingertips and then shouted for help. It was only then that his parents realised he could speak. His mother shouts his father "Look, Look! He can speak."

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
